# Using factory class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I want to create a bean that creates an instance of Client (from Elasticsearch). However I have not configured factory beans in Spring before so I wonder if I got it right after reading. Since the connection should only be opened and closed once I think I must use the factory-bean attribute instead of the static version since I want to invoke the `close` method when the application is shutting down. I did not manage to invoke the `close` method when I used the class attribute.

Is this correct usage? I want only one factory and only one connection, and I want to invoke close on the client when it shuts down.

```
<bean id="clientFactory" class="my.company.ClientFactory" destroy-method="close" />
<bean id="searchClient" factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="getClient" />
```

The factory:

```
public class ClientFactory {

    private Client client;

    public Client getClient() {

        if (client != null) {
            return client;
        }

        Client transportClient = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
        client = transportClient;

        return client;
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch

Comment: it looks right, did it work? I think the way you're forcing a singleton might be overkill.  Spring has a concept of "scope" on a bean - and the default is singleton, meaning Spring will keep reusing the same instance.

Comment: @jeff Singleton on the factory yes, but what do you think happens with the client inside the factory when you instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks close enough. I recommend validation by execution. Maybe write a piece of code to test it. That will be faster than getting someone here to do it for you.